# Can maven use both local and remote repositories?

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project running perfectly using the pom.xml file to get the needed jar files.  Unfortunately the database I connect to doesn't have any jar files out on mvnrepository.  Right now they're sitting in the Referenced Libraries folder.

[image]

Since these files are proprietary I need to keep them local.  I've set up Apache Archiva and have added the files.

Can I get my project pom file to reference both a remote repository and a local repository?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, something like this:

```
 <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                          https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
      <localRepository/>
      <interactiveMode/>
      <usePluginRegistry/>
      <offline/>
      <pluginGroups/>
      <servers/>
      <mirrors/>
      <proxies/>
      <profiles/>
      <activeProfiles/>
    </settings>
```

For more details on this you can look over [here](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html).

You can also look at this [article](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-set-the-location-of-my-local-maven-repository.html).

With the following configuration you can achieve it:

```
<localRepository>/dev/m2repo</localRepository>
```

Comment: How does this solve the OP's problem? His problem is that third-party jars don't even exist in any repository (local or remote).

Answer (score 2):

> Can I get my project pom file to reference both a remote repository and a local repository?

That's how Maven already works. Dependencies are first looked up in your local repository and if not present, they are downloaded from the remote repository to the local repository. In this case, your third-party Jars need to be either installed in your local repository, or better yet deployed to the remote repository so that other developers can use them.

1. **Ideally** you would deploy these third party libraries to a remote repository using a repository manager like Sonatype Nexus. If you are using a Nexus repository manager, see https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/using-sect-uploading.html for how to do this. This would apply to your exact scenario, as the linked page describes:

   > When your build makes use of proprietary or custom dependencies that are not available from public repositories, you will often need to find a way to make them available to developers in a custom Maven repository. Nexus Repository Manager Pro and Nexus Repository Manager OSS ship with a preconfigured third-party repository that was designed to hold third-party dependencies that are used in your builds.

   This can also be done using the [maven-deploy-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html) but requires you to configure in the pom.xml the target repository as described in the documentation.

   **EDIT:**

   You mention using Apache Archiva which is also a repository manager that allows you to deploy the artifacts to its repository. https://archiva.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/deploy.html explains how to do it. https://archiva.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/using-repository.html explains how to configure Maven to get dependencies from an Archiva repository.
2. You can also install the libraries only to your local repository by running the `maven-install-plugin`:

   > ```
   > mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
   > -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
   > ```

   See https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html. The drawback is that other developers have to do this step in order to build their projects.